# Issue in getting active MAC address

Tags: c#, macos, xamarin, mac-address

I use this code to get the MAC address of my macOS system,

```
var firstMacAddress = NetworkInterface
  .GetAllNetworkInterfaces()
  .Where(nic => nic.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up 
    && nic.NetworkInterfaceType != NetworkInterfaceType.Loopback)
  .Select(nic => nic.GetPhysicalAddress().ToString());
  //.FirstOrDefault();
```

It gives an array of all the MAC addresses as shown here

[image]

But in the SystemPreferences, it is the 2nd in the list?

As you see in the System Preference it is "F018....." MAC Address, which is 2nd in the list above.

How do I filter the right one?

[image]

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do as you are getting all the interfaces that are up ad not loopback? Which interface are you expecting to get?

Comment: One option, remove the `.Select` and then inspect the list for comparisons to the one you need. You then can add additional filters based on what you find. As of right now, there's not enough information to help.